Spring boot AWS CORS issue
I have reactjs app deployed in AWS Amplify and hosted with url: https://example.com.
I have spring boot app deployed in EC2 instance and getting accessed from NGINX server with api.example.com.
reactjs is communicating with backend using https://api.example.com/...
When I ran in chrome with security disables(CORS also disabled), its able to get data.
But in normal chrome/mozilla its giving CORS error.
I added CORS in spring boot config as:
    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() throws Exception{
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*")); // Allow all origins
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);

        config.addExposedHeader("code");
        config.addExposedHeader("reason");            

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();

        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        log.info(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(config));
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

Also after searching a lot I added config in vi /etc/nginx/sites-available/api.example.com as
upstream backend-service-api.example.com {
    server localhost:8080;
    #server search - service - 3: 8082;
}


server {


    server_name api.example.com;

    location /{
        proxy_pass https://example.com;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }


    location ~* "^/api/backapp-service(/|$)(.*)" {
    rewrite "(?i)/api/backapp-service(/|$)(.*)" /$2 break;

    # Handle preflight requests
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://example.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain';
        return 204;                                                                                                                                      
                return 204;
    }

    # Handle actual requests
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://example.com';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';

    proxy_pass http://backend-service-api.example.com;
}
    location ~* "^/media(/|$)(.*)" {
        rewrite "(?i)/media(/|$)(.*)" /$2 break;                                                                                                    
        root /home/ubuntu/PRODUCTION/FileServer;
    }

     error_page 401 = @error401;
    location @error401 {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://example.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        return 401;
    }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.example.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}



server {
    if ($host = api.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;


    server_name api.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}   

but still CORS issue giving. Need your suggestions.
when  curl -I -X OPTIONS https://api.example.com/api/backapp-service/products/v1/search-product
response header
HTTP/1.1 200
Server: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 30 Oct 2024 15:19:09 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
reason: Invalid JWT token::CharSequence cannot be null or empty.
code: 401
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS
Accept-Patch:
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://example.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true


are you using any cdn like cloudfront which maybe overriding the response headers ? Did you check the response headers in chrome network tab to see if the cors headers are present ?

When I am hitting api.example.com/product/search...its giving proper response header....but not from ajax call

The issue you're facing is not just a CORS problem, but a broader security concern. When you have a React app deployed on AWS Amplify and a Spring Boot backend deployed on an EC2 instance, you need to ensure that the communication between the two is secure.
Since your React app is hosted on AWS Amplify, it's already using HTTPS, which is a good start. This ensures that the communication between the client (browser) and your React app is secure.
To ensure secure communication between your React app and the Spring Boot backend, you need to configure your Spring Boot application to use HTTPS as well. You cannot invoke Spring Boot using HTTP. This can be done by setting up an SSL/TLS certificate for your API endpoint.
One of the reasons why I prefer API Gateway and Lambda. When you deploy API Gateway endpoints/Lambda functions - it uses HTTPS and you React app can communicate with it without these issues.

Thanks for replying... spring boot app is also secure with letsencrypt... But still facing issue...any other thoughts
